# Why is my integer variable being added to my other integer variable?

Tags: cs50

I am writing a program that counts the amount of letters and words in a string given by the user. For some reason, the number of words is being added to the number of letters. If there is 3 words in the sentence and 12 letters, then it says that there is 15 words. My code is below:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int storeLetters[] = {};
int storeWords[] = {};

// declare functions
int count_letters(string text);
int count_words(string text);

int main(void)
{
    // ask user for text passage
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int numOfLetters = count_letters(text);
    printf("%d",numOfLetters);
    printf(" letters\n");
    int numOfWords = count_words(text);
    printf("%d",numOfWords);
    printf(" words\n");
}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    int amountOfLetters = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            storeLetters[i] += 1;
            amountOfLetters += storeLetters[i];
        }
        else
        {
            storeLetters[i] += 0;
            amountOfLetters += storeLetters[i];
        }
    }
        return amountOfLetters;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    int amountOfWords = 0;
    for (int x = 0, n = strlen(text); x < n; x++)
    {
        if (text[x] == '?' || text[x] == '!' || text[x] == '.' || text[x] == ' ')
        {
            storeWords[x] += 1;
            amountOfWords += storeWords[x];
        }
        else
        {
            storeWords[x] += 0;
            amountOfWords += storeWords[x];
        }
    }
    return amountOfWords;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`storeLetters` and `storeWords` are arrays, which you initialize to zero length. If you access `storeLetters[0]` (or any other index), you go past the end. It's not gonna work.

You don't need those variables at all. Just increment `amountOfLetters` directly.

```
int count_letters(string text)
{
    int amountOfLetters = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            amountOfLetters += 1;
        }
    }
    return amountOfLetters;
}
```

Comment: It's a little hard for me to understand what you are saying about the arrays, but it makes sense. Thank you very much, it worked!

Comment: @Joshua-Michael Arrays cannot be resized after creating them. Normally you would initialize arrays to a specific length, for example: `int storeLetters[20]`. If the array has 20 cells, you can use indexes from 0 to 19. Using index 50 (for example) would be past the end.